# Release SqlConnection without "finally"

Tags: c#, ado.net

I got a task to maintain a c# project, I found some code like this:

```
try{ 

    conn.Open(); 
    ... 
    conn.Close(); 
}catch(Exception e){ 

    conn.Close(); 
}
```

I know that the usual way to close SqlConnection is try-catch-finally or "using" keyword, but I found that I can't prove the code above is wrong, I can't find any situation that the Connection will be leak.

So could you give me some technical advises(not programming style) for it?Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't find *any* situation? What about when that `...` code contains a `return` statement? In a loop, `continue` and `break` can also fit the bill.

Your particular code apparently doesn't contain any control-flow statements, but that's beside the point. The point is that when you use the common resource-acquisition idioms, such as try-finally and using, you no longer need to worry about what the rest of the code is. The `...` can be one line or a hundred lines; whatever resource you acquired at the top will get released at the bottom if you've done it right. Rather than spend time trying to think of *other* ways that might be right (and having to prove it), use the ways you *know* are right because they were designed to be right.

Besides, even if you can prove that the code never leaks a connection, it's still a lousy idea for `conn.Close()` to be the command that has to solve *every* possible exception your program could ever throw. Don't catch exceptions that you don't know how to resolve.

Comment: Actually there is only a ExecuteNonQuery in "..."

Comment: "use the ways you know are right because they were designed to be right."
"Don't catch exceptions that you don't know how to resolve."
That's the point.Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 4):

The connection is `IDisposable`, so wrap it with `using` statement:

```
using(conn) {
  ...
}
```

It should provide the best insurance for you. It should even close the connection if you will `return` from using block (as correctly mentioned, is often a hidden issue).

Answer (score 3):

If

```
conn.Close();
```

throws an Exception.

Comment: I think this is possible to break the worlflow.Could yuo give me more about how to make the close failed and throw an exception?

Comment: The point of the using block is to call IDispose.  In the case of most ADO.NET connections, this also calls Close.  However, IDispose may also execute other code which would not get called with your snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

I'll approach this question a little differently. I prefer `using` or `try`/`finally` over the above because it avoids the redundancy. In keeping with the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) I would rather not have to remember to call `Close()` twice. Avoiding this makes the code easier to write and maintain. Apart from that the other answers have to good points to consider as well.

Answer (score 1):

Kill the connection between the conn.Open() and the ExecuteNonQuery() call and I think it *should* throw an Exception and thus leak the connection object.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect code is here...

```
            try
            {
                if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    Conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message + " : dbOperation.ExecuteNonQuery()");
            }
            finally
            {
                 if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Conn.Closed();
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: -1: this code truncates the stack trace and severely maims all the other information carried in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        // other codes

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

        // Create a (useful) error message
        string ErrorMessage = "A error occurred while trying to connect to the server.";
        ErrorMessage += Environment.NewLine;
        ErrorMessage += Environment.NewLine;
        ErrorMessage += Ex.Message;

        // Show error message (this = the parent Form object)
        lblMessage.Text = "Error: " + ErrorMessage;

    }
    finally
    {
        // close connection
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is equivalent to

```
try{ 

    conn.Open(); 
    ... 
}catch(Exception e){     
}finally{
    conn.Close(); 
}
```

So there should be no leak. Personally I prefer the finally way.

Answer (score -2):

```
try
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    conn.Open();
    ..........
    conn.Close();
}
Catch{}
```